# SQL Stored Procedure using results of main query in a subquery

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I've got a stored procedure made for my Crystal Reports. It does not work yet and I haven't got an idea on how to fix this.. This is my query:

```
use [fmsAir];
WITH Main AS (
    SELECT  [File].[FileNumber], [CostRevenue].[COSTAMOUNT], [CostRevenue].[RevenueAmount], [File].[FileDate], [CostRevenue].[REVENUERATE], [CostRevenue].[CostRate], [CostRevenue].[REVENUECURRENCY],
            [File].[COMPANY], [CostRevenue].[CRNUMBER], [CostRevenue].[IINVOICENUMBER], [File].[RELATIONCODE], [CostRevenue].[COSTRELATIONCODE], [CostRevenue].[REVENUEDESCRIPTION]
    FROM    
            [fmsAir].[dbo].[File]
    INNER JOIN
            [fmsAir].[dbo].[CostRevenue] ON [File].[FILENUMBER] = [CostRevenue].FILENUMBER
    WHERE
            [File].[FILEDATE] BETWEEN '2016-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-01-20 00:00:00' AND
            [File].[FILENUMBER] > 500
),
Relation AS (
    SELECT [Relation].[Companyname], [Relation].[RELATIONCODE]
    FROM [fms].[dbo].[Relation]
    WHERE [Relation].[Relationcode] = Main.[File].[RELATIONCODE]
),
OutgoingInvoiceLine AS (
    SELECT [OutgoingInvoiceLine].[AMOUNT], [OutgoingInvoiceLine].[RATE], [OutgoingInvoiceLine].[Currency], [OutgoingInvoiceLine].[CRNUMBER]
    FROM [fmsAir].[dbo].[OutgoingInvoiceLine]
    WHERE [OutgoingInvoiceLine].[CRNUMBER] = Main.[CostRevenue].[CRNUMBER]
),
IncomingInvoiceLine AS (
    SELECT [IncomingInvoiceLine].[AMOUNT], [IncomingInvoiceLine].[RATE], [IncomingInvoiceLine].[CURRENCY], [IncomingInvoiceLine].[CRNUMBER]
    FROM [fmsAir].[dbo].[IncomingInvoiceLine]
    WHERE [IncomingInvoiceLine].[CRNUMBER] = Main.[CostRevenue].[CRNUMBER]
),
RelationCost AS (
    SELECT [Relation].[CompanyNAME], [Relation].[RelationCode]
    FROM [fms].[dbo].[Relation]
    WHERE Relation.RELATIONCODE = Main.[CostRevenue].[COSTRELATIONCODE]
)
SELECT main.FILENUMBER, main.COSTAMOUNT from Main
```

Now the part where i use WHERE and then the Main.*.* it does not work because that is not the way you can use it, but I do not know a way on how to do it the right way either. Can anybody help me make this work?

These are the errors:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   The multi-part identifier "Main.File.RELATIONCODE" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 21 The multi-part identifier
>   "Main.CostRevenue.CRNUMBER" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16,
>   State 1, Line 26 The multi-part identifier "Main.CostRevenue.CRNUMBER"
>   could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 31 The
>   multi-part identifier "Main.CostRevenue.COSTRELATIONCODE" could not be
>   bound.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: What's this got to do with MySQL?

Comment: Using CTE's you dont need to reference the source table.
Main.[CostRevenue].[CRNUMBER] should be Main.[CRNUMBER] for example

Comment: @vice that also does not work... :S Same thing. it could not be bound...

Answer (score 0):

Try to Create the column name in the cte expression and use that column name in the below mentioned cte.
I hope this will help

Comment: This does not work... I have all the column name like this: WITH Main ([FileNumber], [COSTAMOUNT], [RevenueAmount], [FileDate], [REVENUERATE], [CostRate], [REVENUECURRENCY], [COMPANY], [CRNUMBER], [IINVOICENUMBER], [RELATIONCODE], [COSTRELATIONCODE], [REVENUEDESCRIPTION]) AS (

Answer (score 0):

Why your are using 4 cte if you are only fetching the result from only first cte table.

Comment: In the end, i want to fetch from all of them.

Comment: This Error generally occur when we are having some duplicate column name as the column name of the above cte and the the column name of the derived cte exactly match with each other.